# Arrange my list of products in rows

Tags: html, css, razor

I am currently learning asp.net mvc stuffs and multiple trial and error on designing my product page, I am lost on how to arrange my product in row. As currently it stacks vertical 1 after another like

e.g

Product 1

Product 2

Product 3

Product 4

Where instead i wanted to make it like

e.g

```
Product 1  Product 2  Product 3 Product 4
```

This is the area which I think I should be changing but I've tried multiple things such as inline-block, float:left but there's no change

Here is my code for the product section, any help on how it can arrange by like 4 by 3 as there are 12 products only as I am currently learning.

Thank you in advance!

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title" style="font-size:24px"><strong>Products</strong></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <table cellpadding="10" data-bind="foreach: contactLens">
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <div class="entire-package">
                                <img width="255" height="190" data-bind="attr: { src: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ Image }" />
                                <div class="detail-design">
                                    <strong><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></strong> <br />
                                    Type: <span data-bind="text: Type"></span><br />
                                    Brand: <span data-bind="text: Brand"></span> <br />
                                    Price: <span data-bind="text: Price"></span> <br />
                                    Amount: <span data-bind="text: Amount"></span> <br />
                                    <a href="#" data-bind="click:$parent.getProductDetails" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="font-size:18px">Details</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" data-bind="visible: error"><p data-bind="text: error"></p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a `data-bind="foreach:..."` on the `div` that is `col-md-4`. The way your code is at the minute, you're creating *one* column, 4-wide and just having x number of tables inside that. You need to "loop" through the products and place them into the "column"s - also look into the different `col-xs`/`sm`/`md`/`lg` available to get the responsiveness how you like.

Comment: Hmm...is that `<tr>` included within your `foreach`? That could be a problem, since each `<tr>` results in a new table row...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how it could look like.

```
<html>
<body>
  <table style="width:50%">
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Brand</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Value</td>
      <td>Value</td>
      <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse; }
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
   text-align: left; }
</style>
```